# Getting relativePath and then diving deeper

Tags: java

I have a package structure like

```
A
|_B
|_C
  |_D
    |_"myFile.txt"
myMain.java
```

In my main i want to do something like

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
```

Which gives me the current relative path to where my Main() is located. Something along the lines of /home/myprojects/project1/src/ How do I amend the above to get me the relative path all the way down to the level of myFile.txt?

I have tried things like:

```
 Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("" + "/B/C/D/");
```

and

```
 Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("","B/C/D/");
```

and

```
 Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
 Path finalPath = Paths.get(currentRelativePath.toString(),"/B/C/D/");
```

But in each case it only gets the "/B/C/D/" portion and not the beginning of the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Gets from the current working directory a path to B/C/D
Path path = Paths.get("B/C/D");
//String equal to "B/C/D"
path.toString();
//String equal to "/home/myprojects/project1/src/B/C/D"
path.toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

I think you are confusing relative and absolute paths. /home/myprojects/project1/src/ is an absolute path, not as you say in your question "the current relative path"